# OPC Controls Components missing

Tags: asp.net, opc

I'm partly developing opc client application using asp.net and I'm facing some problem. I just want to read some tag value from an opc server. The main problem is I cannot find the OPC Control Components in the Toolbox. I also tried to add it into the toolbox, but I cannot find any of the OPC Components. I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and Kepware.
Please help me to find a way to add the components.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say "I'm using ...Kepware", does that mean that you are connecting to a Kepware server, or that you are using their client product (ClientAce?)

Comment: I'm using KEPServerEX 6

Comment: So, what is then the "OPC Controls Components" you are looking for in the Toolbox? I mean, which OPC client library should they come from? Or do you have no such library installed, and you somehow expect the OPC components appear in the Toolbox just because you have the KEPServerEx?

Comment: I'm looking for OPC Controls such as OPCAlarmControls, OPCControlsButton, etc. in the toolbox which can connect to my OPC server. I cannot understand why I cannot find any of these!

Comment: You need to install some OPC Client toolkit/library that provides these controls or functionality. They do not come with Visual Studio, and they do not come with OPC server, normally.

Comment: Which toolkit/library should I use for ASP.NET applications?

Comment: Well this is a kind of question that, by the rules, should (at least ideally) be avoided on StackOverflow. But anyway. I am not aware of specific one for that purpose. And I (this is a disclaimer - "self promotion") represent OPC Labs which has such product (QuickOPC, http://www.opclabs.com/products/quickopc ). It supports ASP.NET, but it has no visual controls for the Web; you would just use client object to make the OPC operations, and it would be up to you to hook it up with actual user interface elements.